# MongoDB - is this query possibile with denormalized model?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have this simple Mongodb document:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("55663d9361cfa81a5c48d54f")
            "name" : "Oliver",
            "surname" : "Queen",
            "age" : 25,
            "friends" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Jhon",
                        "surname" : "Diggle",
                        "age" : "30"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Barry",
                        "surname" : "Allen",
                        "age" : "24"
                }
        ]
}
```

Is it possbile, using denormalized model as above, to find all Oliver's friends with 24 years old?
I think it's really simple with normalized model; it's enough to do two queries.
For example the following query:

```
db.collection.find({name:"Oliver", "friends.age":24}, {_id:0, friends:1})
```

returns an array of Oliver's friends. Is it possible to make a selection of the *internal document*?

Comment: What output do you want? Can you edit your question showing desired output?

Comment: you should use [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/aggregation-examples/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/)

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { "name": "Oliver" }},
        { $unwind: "$friends" }, 
        { $match: { "friends.age": 24 }}, 
        { $group: { "_id": "$_id", friends: { "$push": "$friends" }}}, 
        { $project: { "_id": 0, "friends": 1 }}
    ]
)
```